# What I must do for taking cmd(64-bits) when I type cmd

Tags: windows-8, cmd.exe

Now when I type cmd I obtain cmd (32-bits).

I need to get cmd (64-bits)

Comment: What makes you think you are getting 32-bits?

Comment: Are you running a 64-bit version of Windows?

Comment: I use a 64-bit version of windows 8.1Pro. I can type `c:\windows\syswow64\cmd.exe`

Comment: `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe` is 64-bit. Why are you running the one in `c:\windows\syswow64` which is 32-bit? Is your `PATH` broken?

Comment: I would have never imagined that in a directory named system32 there was a 64-bit app and in a directory named syswow64 there was a 32-bit app. I have a problem with colors.

Comment: So what is your actual problem? Please [edit] the question and explain.

Comment: I write my question in http://superuser.com/questions/1096738/how-i-get-normal-colors-in-c-windows-system32-cmd-exe.

Comment: Can you post some link to read about folders in windows (32 bits vs 64 bits)? Then I delete this questin. Thanks

Comment: I've added an answer about "about folders in windows (32 bits vs 64 bits)".

Comment: We don't delete questions when they have good answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### I need to get cmd (64-bits)

The 64-bit `cmd.exe` is located in `C:\Windows\System32`

---

#### Two different versions of the Program Files folder and the Windows System folder

> A 64-bit Windows has two different versions of the program files
> folder and the Windows system folder (system directory). One version
> is intended for 32-bit files and other version is intended for 64-bit
> files. The name of these folders, and the bitness they are intended
> for, is shown in the table below:
>
> [image]
>
> Below you can see the full path to the folders.
>
> [image]
>
> The 'System32' folder is for 64-bit files and the 'SysWOW64' folder is
> for 32-bit files   This can be somewhat confusing, but the System32
> folder is intended for 64-bit files and the SysWOW64 folder is
> intended for 32-bit files. This may seem a bit illogical if you look
> at the folder names, but there is an explanation to this. It has to do
> with compatibility.
>
> Many developers have hard coded the path to the system folder in their
> applications source code. They have included "System32" in the folder
> path. And to preserve compatibility, if the application is converted
> to 64-bit code, the 64-bit system folder is still named System32.
>
> But what about 32-bit applications that have the system path hard
> coded and is running in a 64-bit Windows? How can they find the new
> SysWOW64 folder without changes in the program code, you might think.
>
> The answer is that the emulator redirects calls to System32 folder to
> the SysWOW64 folder transparently so even if the folder is hard coded
> to the System32 folder (like C:\Windows\System32), the emulator will
> make sure that the SysWOW64 folder is used instead.
>
> So same source code, that contains a path with the System32 folder
> included, can be compiled to both 32-bit and 64-bit program code
> without any changes.

Source [Windows 64-bit: The 'Program Files (x86)' and 'SysWOW64' folders explained](http://www.samlogic.net/articles/32-64-bit-windows-folder-x86-syswow64.htm)