# How I get normal colors in c:/windows/system32/cmd.exe without reseting others settings

Tags: windows-8, cmd.exe, colors

Currently when I use cmd.exe the red color is too dark and the blue and green colors don't apears. In other computers I don't have this problem. Using c:/windows/syswow64/cmd.exe in my computer I don't have this problem.

Previously I didn't change anything.

How I get normal colors?

The answers of the question [How to reset the looks of the Command Prompt window, in Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/609470/how-to-reset-the-looks-of-the-command-prompt-window-in-windows) refers to reset all the look. I need only to undertand the colors.

Comment: I don't want to reset all. I want to talk about colors

Comment: Please [edit] and provide a screenshot to help us understand your problem.

Comment: I thought that this question doesn't already have a complete answer.

Comment: @magicandre1981,  My question and the anwer is similar but not the same. It has a refined need and the answer has more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [How to reset the looks of the Command Prompt window, in Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/609470/how-to-reset-the-looks-of-the-command-prompt-window-in-windows) and others sources I obtain a more precise answer:

## To change colors in cmd

I went to window register and look at two entries:

- HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\%SystemRoot%_system32_cmd.exe
- HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console

In the second one I have the normal colors. In the first one I have several color definition with the value 000000 (that corresponds with black), thats the reason beause I didn't see green and blue colors.

- ColorTable00 = 000000 (black)
- ColorTable01 = 800000 (blue)
- ColorTable02 = 008000 (green)
- ColorTable03 = 808000 (cyan)
- ColorTable04 = 000080 (red)
- ColorTable05 = 800080 (magenta)
- ColorTable06 = 008080 (yellow)